# Is declaring const keywords required with the equality operator?

Tags: c++, struct, constants, operator-keyword

I was watching [this seminar on C++ best practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqfgOCU_Do4), and the speaker gave this code example:

```
struct Data{
  int x;
  int y;

  bool operator==(Data &rhs){
   return x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y;
}
};
```

He then asked what was missing in this code. As a newbie I thought that nothing was missing, but then he pointed out that 2 `const` keywords were missing, like so:

```
struct Data{
  int x;
  int y;

    bool operator==(const Data &rhs) const{
     return x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y;
  }
};
```

Now I think this is like a promise not to modify the object. But can someone explain why these `const` keywords are necessary?

Comment: I would expect that this "seminar on c++ best practices" will also explain why this is mandatory. After well, what the point of having a "seminar on c++ best practices" when it doesn't explain the reason for these best practices?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik He did not explain. Here is the link to the video if you are interesed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqfgOCU_Do4

Comment: fyi (not an exact duplicate) [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading).  Also [Comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) - typical/expected signatures.

Comment: There is nothing special about `operator==` in this context. The reasons for using `const` here are the same reasons you would have for any function or method that you write.

Comment: As the 'basic rules' link above explains, it is generally thought that `operator==` should be implemented as a non-member function. This is best practice, so that doesn't say much for the best practice video you are watching.

Comment: I'd also consider to add `[[nodiscard]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you did not have `const` on both places in your `operator==`, this would not compile:

```cpp
void foo(const Data& lhs, const Data& rhs) {
    if(lhs == rhs) { // requires `operator==(const Data &rhs) const`
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

> why is this mandatory

It is not - but it's good practice - and failing to implement it that way will severely inhibit the ability to interact with the standard (and other) libraries.

1. Your aim is not to change the value of the parameter you take by reference. If that parameter is `const` and you take it by a `const&` you will therefore still be able to read from it in your function. Had your declaration only said `Data& rhs`, it would not compile.
2. Your aim is not to change the state of `*this` (the lefthand side of the `==` operator). The same applies here. If `*this` is `const`, the `const` qualifier on the member function makes it still possible to use the member function.